# Can't Truncate Table Befor Seeding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, lumen

I want to truncate my user table befor seed.i do like this :

**DatabaseSeeder.php :**

```php
 <?php

 use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

 class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
 {
     public function run()
     {
         App\User::truncate();

         factory(App\User::class,1)->create();
     }
 }
```

Then run **`php artisan db:seed`** and have error:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constra
  int (`mr_musicer`.`dislikes`, CONSTRAINT `dislikes_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `mr_musicer`
  .`users` (`id`)) (SQL: truncate `users`)


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constra
  int (`mr_musicer`.`dislikes`, CONSTRAINT `dislikes_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `mr_musicer`
  .`users` (`id`))
```

I want to now why i can't truncate my user table!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is foreign key problem and table is trying to remind it to you.
If you want to truncate table anyway.

```
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

    // ... Some Truncate Query

    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Don't forget To Use:
        `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Comment: I made a package `snowbuilds/laravel-seeder-reset` that does exactly this, but it also makes truncating optional. Kind of handy if you just want to list the seeders and models to truncate.

Answer (score 3):

Import `DB`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

And then use this piece of code to truncate the table:

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
DB::table('posts')->truncate();
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to truncate the data before seeding when you have foreign keys in the table

Just add this single line at the start of your run method.

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

DB::truncate('posts'); or Post::truncate();

Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Comment: I think it has a mistake, first you should use disableForeignKeyConstraints and after your operations call enableForeignKeyConstraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have references to your users on some other table. You should add `->onDelete('cascade')` to the dislikes table column that references user's id or delete all dislikes manually first.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: i used `cascade` in all of tables like this : `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');`